# how can i get repository headers with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image: I'm trying to get all the repository headers on the page with Selenium]

I tried with find_elements_by_xpath and find_elements_by_css_selector but it returns either an empty list or a selenium type object

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/chromedriver.exe')

url = "http://github.com"

driver.get(url)

search_input = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

search_input.send_keys("python")

search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/main/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")

driver.close()
print(result)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can access those items using CSS selectors

```py
result = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".repo-list-item a.v-align-middle")
```